# Laravel 5.6 PostGres Json default null

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I need to only insert 1 JSON array at a time, thus need the JSON arrays to be default null if no entry. Is there a way I can do this?

Using the approach from: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16107

My migration is

```
Schema::create('job_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('id')->default('0');
    $table->primary('id');
    $table->foreign('id')->references('id')->on('job_searches');
    $table->json('Location_of_job');
    $table->json('API_URL'); 
    $table->json('Redirected_URL'); 
    $table->json('Description'); 
    $table->json('Salary',6,2); 
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Model:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
public $timestamps = true;

protected $fillable = ['API_URL', 'Redirected_URL','Location_of_job','Description','Salary',];

protected $casts = [
    'Location_of_job' => 'array',
    'API_URL' => 'array',
    'Redirected_URL' => 'array',
    'Description' => 'array',
    'Salary' => 'array'
];
protected $attributes = array(
    'json' => '{}'
);
```

Error getting:

> SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column
>   "Location_of_job" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row
>   contains (0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null). (SQL: insert
>   into "job_details" ("API_URL") values (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (),
>   (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#columns):

> To make the column "nullable", you may use the `nullable` method

```
$table->json('Location_of_job')->nullable();
$table->json('API_URL')->nullable(); 
$table->json('Redirected_URL')->nullable(); 
$table->json('Description')->nullable(); 
$table->json('Salary', 6, 2)->nullable();
```

Comment: I was using this before and it wasn't setting them to 'nullable' (In fact, it only worked on timestamps). Not entirely sure if it's working because i defined 'json = {}',  but thank you very much!